# Pass data from a parent component to a service to be added to child component provider array

Tags: angular

I have a child component where I have to inject a service in its constructor. The service would be used only by this child component and therefore I would like to add the service in the providers array in this child component. The service should be created based on values passed from parent component? I want to have only one instance of the service based on passed in value in the constructor of the service. I would then use the instance of this service to call methods available in the service.

Can someone please help with an example? How should I solve this problem? I'm very new to angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but yes you can add a service in the providers array of a component.

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css'],
    providers: [
       ProductService
    ]
})
export class ProductComponent { 
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.serviceData = "some value";
    this.productService.otherData = 7;
  }
}
```

This service is then available to this component and any of its child components.

I didn't understand this part of your question: `The service should be created based on values passed from parent component?`

Do you mean that you want to pass values into the service? You can do that with service properties.

Here is an example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class ProductService{
  serviceData: string;
  otherData: number;
}
```

Or via a method, which from what I've seen, is not a very common technique:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class ProductService{
  serviceData: string;
  otherData: number;

  initializeData(info: string, otherInfo: number): void {
     this.serviceData= info;
     this.otherData = otherInfo;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to pass values into the service constructor. You said we can do it with service properties. Any example please.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, do you mean to say I should have initialise(values) method to pass data to service before I call any other method on the service. The initialise method should be called from ngOnit. Am I right? Would you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Can I also do the same by adding initialize method to pass values ? Does that make any difference  compared to using properties as you've explained?

Comment: Yes, you could use a method instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the service needs to be provided with values from a parent component as soon as it is instantiated, it would be better to provide the service in the parent component's providers list and instantiate it properly there.

Then you can import it and inject it into the constructor of the child component just like you would if it was on its own provider's list, except this way, it will use the instance of the service created by the parent component.

In fact, every descendant component of the parent component will be provided with the same instance of that service if you use dependency injection.

---

Parent Component

```
 import { SomeService } from './somelocation' 

 @Component({ 
   selector: ' ... ',
   providers: [ SomeService ],
   ....
```

Inject the service by passing it to the component constructor, and lets say the service had some property on it (a public property) that was dependent on something in your component. In your component's ngOnInit() method, you could configure that part of your service.

```
 constructor( private someService: SomeService ) { 
  // passing the service in the constructor here makes it available to your component  
 }

 ngOnInit()  {
       if (this.someComponentProperty < 100 ) {
           // this compares some property in the component to 100, and if its less than that, sets the property in the service equal to the property in the component 
           this.someService.someServiceProperty = this.someValue

            // or you could call the service's methods

           this.someService.serviceMethod();  

           // you'll be able to access any public property or method from the service in this component. 
       }

  }
```

---

Child Component

```
 import { SomeService } from './somelocation'
```

in the constructor...

```
 constructor(private someService: SomeService) { ...
```

You'll get the same instance of the service in both components, and this way will ensure the service gets the config values it needs as soon as it needs them, and that you won't have to unnecessarily share properties between components (i.e, you wont need to have the child try to access properties on its parent component just so it can provide those properties to the service)

Comment: In your answer I don't, find how do I pass values to the constructor of the service from the component. Would you please help with an example?

Comment: You wouldn't configure the service by passing parameters to its constructor. You would use dependency injection in the constructor of the parent component to inject the service, and then configure the service by either changing its properties or calling some of its methods. I will update the answer above with an example

Comment: Hi @diopside, would like to ask is it better to let the child components directly get the data from service instead of getting the data in parent component and passing it around?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it well, I have prepared a dummy example of your scenario:

```
/*myparent.component.ts*/
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: "parent-component",
    template: `
        Parent component
        <child-component [values]="valuesForChild"></child-component>
    `
})
export class MyParentComponent {

    valueForChild;

    updateValue () {
        // do smth with "valueForChild" property
    }

}
```

Now the child component:

```
/*mychild.component.ts*/
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from 'path/to/service';

@Component({
    selector: "child-component",
    template: `
        Child component: {{ value }}
    `,
    providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyChildComponent {

    @Input() value;

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.testMethod(value);
    }
    updateValues () {
        // do smth with "value" property taken from parent
    }

}
```

And finally the service:

```
/*myservice.ts*/
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  testMethod(value) { console.log(value) }
}
```

Now some explanations: you noticed I passed the value from parent to child using property binding (the syntax: `[values]="valuesForChild"`) and the child component is able to use it through the `@Input()` decoration. Your service is injected into your child and then it can use/manipulate your child component's properties.